# How do I make a variable interval loop while keeping access to constructor variables?

Tags: javascript, loops, constructor

Good day!

Here is my issue. I have a function, that needs to loop at an interval that changes. However if you do the below:

```js
example.prototype.Start = async Function() {
  setTimeout(this.Function, this.interval)
}

example.prototype.Function = async Function() {
  this.interval++;
  setTimeout(this.Function, this.interval);
}
```

In this example, I believe the "this.interval" should be undefined. Now imagine this.interval can be influenced outside this function too. Which is why I want it as a constructor variable. However, I can't think of a way to get it defined within the loop without getting rid of the context of the variable being the whole constructor. I hope that makes sense.

Edit: Ignore that these are asynchronous functions without reason, in my long code, it has a reason.

Comment: `this.Function.bind(this)`

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: You need to assign to `instance.interval` before you call `instance.Start()`

Comment: Which you can of course do in the constructor

Comment: Yes, that is what I do :)

Comment: It worked. :) Switched my code to use this type of loop instead of a constant loop successfully. Thanks for the help!